# C# and Matlab differences in reading video frame rgb values

Tags: c#, matlab, video, rgb

I'm  trying to convert a matlab script into c#. The matlab script reads an .avi video file and for each frame in the video it calculates the mean value of red, green, and blue pixels and then places them into a matrix. So im storing a red.mean , green.mean, and blue.mean value into a matrix for every frame in the video file.

To achieve this in c# im using the Aforge framework which has an AVIreader class as well as an Image Statistics class which provides the rgb mean values for a given image. The problem I've run into is the mean values matlab calculates for a frame and the mean values c# calculates for a frame are not matching up. They are similar and within .5 or so of one another but I feel like they should be identical.

C# was using 15 sigfigs for the mean so I asked matlab to do the same to remove the chance of rounding errors and it didn't really improve the results.

So Here is the kicker.....

I decided to take a random jpeg image off google and load it into matlab and separate its rgb pixel values into three separate matrices. I chose the r matrix and used the histc() function to count how many r values had a value equal to one of the numbers in the range of 0-255.

Using the same image I did the exact same thing in C# I opened the image converted it to a bitmap and then use Aforge's ImageStatistics to give me a histogram for the r values in the image.

When I compared the histogram given in matlab to that in C# they were very similar but for certain values between 0-255 one histogram would have greater or lesser values than the other.  Essentially, for some reason C# and Matlab interpret the pixel values in the image differently and I would like to know why?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the data type of the RGB matrix in Matlab? It is possible the values are stored as integers.

```
>> A=magic(25);
>> B=uint8(A);
>> mean(mean(A))

ans =

  313

>> mean(mean(B))

ans =

 203.1840

>>
```